# How to set outter varaible from process in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I call by ajax this function. Main purpose is to return HttpResponse object with some data. Data depends on result of login.

def **validate_account** return boolean. How to set **is_valid** varraible from proccess in python?

process.join() is redudant?

```
@login_required
@csrf_protect
def create_account(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        username = ''
        password = ''
        body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        body = json.loads(body_unicode)
        try:
            username = body['username']
            password = body['password']
        except KeyError as e:
            log.exception(e)
            return HttpResponseServerError()

        try:
            accounts_of_user = Account.objects.get(username=username)

            if accounts_of_user:
                return HttpResponse('901', content_type='text/plain')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:

            is_valid = False

            def new_process():
                is_valid = validate_account(username=username, password=password)

            process = Process(target=new_process())
            process.daemon = True
            process.start()
            process.join()
            process.terminate()

            print(is_valid)

            if is_valid:
                signer = Signer(salt='extra')
                account = Account()

                account.username = username
                account.password = signer.sign(password)
                account.save()

                request.session['current_account'] = username
                return HttpResponse('902', content_type='text/plain')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('903', content_type='text/plain')


    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Comment: the `nonlocal` keyword might do it but I'd like to know more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Right now you're running `new_process()` in the main thread and creating a process whose target is None (because that's what `new_process` returns). Is that intentional?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen question was updated

Comment: @Kevin Do you think that target is None? Hm, trully speaking, I don]t understand you, because process runs properly.

Comment: @ArtemDumanov when you do `...(target=new_process())` it runs `new_process()` and sets target equal to the result (which is `None` since the function doesn't return anything). You mean to do `...(target=new_process)`

Comment: Notably, that's not a daemon process, and if it were, subsequently calling `join` and `terminate` on it would be very wrong.

Comment: @AdamSmith So, if target function will return value, I can retrieve it from outter scope?

Comment: No you need to set up messaging to do that. It's not a great idea. Processes don't share memory, so you can't have a process change state in your main line. Why are you trying to multiprocess this? It seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @AdamSmith so, call of join() and terminate is redudant? How I can clear memory from process? Or it will clear automaticaly?

Comment: @AdamSmith yeah, you was right. It is redudant to create a new process. Thank you.